# How to send username and password to facebook from windows application

Tags: c#, html, facebook, desktop-application, windows

how can i send username and password from 2 text boxes from desktop application to Facebook login page to login by them ? i mean if can i send the data from text boxes located in my desktop application to the username text box or in html 
 tag  in Facebook website

Comment: No, you can’t. (Facebook takes extensive measures to prevent you from using any kind of automated tools to use their site.) And apps are forbidden from asking users for their login credentials in general. If you want to interact with Facebook in any way – use their API.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're not supposed to capture the Facebook username/password in an application and pass it on, all applications I've seen lately open a web browser to allow the user to log in and use the returned token for access.

Answer (score 1):

Like CBroe stated, it is forbidden to ask for users login information.

Here is documentation for the Facebook Login Api, take a lot it should have some solutions for you.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login